# setting dynamic x coordinate of second lable in xcode objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uilabel

i have a problem that i have two lables,

1) will contain a long text 
2) this will be just More button (link)

so i want that when the first text ends then the second label starts right from where it end. but the problem is that the text is variable so i could not find any way to make it dynamic.
example

text of first row
"this is text of first label" "more"

text of second line
"test best" "more"

in the example the rows are of table view and two lables are separated by " so i want second label starting point from where the text in first lable ends

looking forward for some solution

Thanks & Regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSString` has some methods to calculate its size when displaying using given font (e.g. `sizeWithFont:` method) - you can use it to determine text width and place your more button accordingly (someZZZZ parameters must be available on runtime):

```
CGFloat firstLabelWidth = [firstLabel.text sizeWithFont:firstLabel.font].width;
CGFloat moreX = firstLabel.frame.origin.x + firstLabelWidth + someGap;
moreButton.frame = CGRectMake(moreX, moreY, someWidth, someHeight);
```

You may need to add some validation for cases when text in first label is too long to fit the screen etc, but in general this code should work.